# Monitoring outbound server http header information?

Tags: linux, http-headers, centos

What tool / function can we use on our linux server running CentOS to monitor the http headers that are sent from our application to another application on a different server? Looking for http header monitoring from server to server. My issue is I have no idea how to capture the data sent from the server, meaning the http headers sent via a post. I have tried many methods and third party software's like fiddler2 and ieinspector and the list goes on, but they only seem to capture the client headers and not what is being sent out from the server. I just need to capture the string being sent out via a post function and what is being returned. Seems simple, yet in this case, I'm beyond lost and running out of time to resolve what should be a simple solution. Please advise & thank you kindly.

Comment: Why does it matter where you capture the headers? If you use Fiddler, you'll capture the headers the server sends to the client where Fiddler is running.

Comment: We can see the headers from the server to the client using fiddler2, however, our application is calling an api on a different server. So the sequence goes - client to server - server to server - server back to server - server back to client. We cannot tell if the http headers sent from our server to the other server are correct.

Comment: The other server's support personnel are unable to capture that information & are forcing us to uncover the data.  We know what we think we are sending, but cannot verify it. What we want is a fiddler2 like tool that resides on our server to track this, that can monitor the server to server traffic. If fiddler2 can do this, please let us know how to do this. Thank you for any direction or help.